# Vlcj change video background color

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj

I'm creating a narrative application in which I need to play videos.

When playing a media with `MediaPlayer.playMedia(Media media)`.
In order to avoid the black background I wait the wait for the playing event before showing the media player.

```
        player.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void playing(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                showVideo();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that this event is triggered before the video actually starts playing, so it still displays black for a little while before.

How can I find a way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for certain, but you could try some other event listener methods - perhaps the videoOutput, elementaryStreamAdded or elementaryStreamSelected (and check the stream type parameter was video), or maybe wait for the very first positionChanged event (whilst not ideal, it might work well enough for your use case).

Comment: Thank you. I had no results with the other events but the positionChanged evenr worked well enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: Just a follow-up, with vlcj-3.12.1 you can now wait for mediaPlayerReady event to serve the same purpose (it's essentially the same thing as waiting for that first positionChanged event).